# How can I use the following script?

Tags: nsis

I want to delete all files except the Bookmarks file from the Default folder. But the following code does not work. I know I should use the Batch file, but is there a way to use the code below? Thank you for any help

ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c "SET "sourcedir=$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Default" & SET "keepfile=Bookmarks" & FOR %a IN ("%sourcedir%*") DO IF /i NOT "%~nxa"=="%keepfile%" DEL "%a""'

Comment: You tagged this as NSIS but your question is about batch syntax? Why not just code this in NSIS instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
Section "Prepare example"
SetOutPath "$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Default"
SetOverwrite off
File "/oname=$outdir\Bookmarks" "${__FILE__}"
File "/oname=$outdir\Blah" "${__FILE__}"
File "/oname=$outdir\Footmarks" "${__FILE__}"
SectionEnd

!include LogicLib.nsh

Section

StrCpy $2 "$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Default"
FindFirst $0 $1 "$2\*"
loop:
    StrCmp $1 "" done
    StrCmp $1 . next
    StrCmp $1 .. next
    ${If} $1 != "Bookmarks"
        Delete "$2\$1"
    ${EndIf}
next:
    FindNext $0 $1
    Goto loop
done:
FindClose $0

SectionEnd
```

Comment: You really are a genius. Exactly what I wanted. It works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: you should mark it as the answer then...